# using electron-store with ip as key

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Hy,

i try to use electron-store to persist values by ip as key.
Using the code:

```
store.set('users.' + ip, 'foo')
```

So i want to achieve following object:

> {users: [{"192.186.0.0": "foo"},{"192.186.0.1": "bar"}]}

but what i got is

> "192": {
> "168": {
> "192": {
> "151": "Foo",
> "134": "Bar",.....

So is there a way to use ips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want is essentially an array of objects, where the objects key is the ip address. In this case though I would rather recommend using an array of arrays because it makes working with the data a bit easier.

So first we create a new Map, which holds our users ip and name:

```
let map=new Map();
map.set('192.186.0.0', 'foo');
map.set('192.186.0.1', 'bar');
```

To store this Map using electron-store, we need to pack it into an array and populate the `users` key.

```
store.set('users', Array.from(map.entries(map)));
```

If we want to read out or modify values from the users key, we need to convert the array back to a map.

Let's look at an example - we want to modify `192.186.0.0` to say `title` instead of `foo`:

```
let map=new Map(store.get('users'));
map.set('192.186.0.0', 'title');
store.set('users', Array.from(map.entries(map)));
```

Comment: It was not possible for me to use this. But it is helpful anyway. What i did was. ``` ip.replaceAll('.','') ``` so i got {users: [{"19218600": "foo"},{"19218601": "bar"}]}